# Check for empty db column value and return results - c# asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, while-loop

I got a great response the last time I posted here.

I have the following table structure in my database for a small Gallery page on my site.

```
id | title | img1 | img1sml | img2 | img2sml | img3 | img3sml
```

Now, `id` and `title` are mandatory, however the rest are not.

I'd like to loop through all my `sml` columns that have values in them and create `<img src="--column value here--" />` for each of them.

I'd also like to do the same with my `img` columns - loop through any non-empty columns and list them

Can someone show me how I can do this?

Many thanks for any help with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check `NULL` as follows

```
if(!YourObject.Equals(System.DBNull.Value))
```

Comment: Hi Thomas. Just to be clear, would this go in my CodeBehind file? Here's my current code `string ID = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, title, body, img1sml, img1, img2sml, img2, img3sml, img3, img4sml, img4 FROM news WHERE ID = " + ID, conn);
                // Open connection
                conn.Open();

                // Execute the command
                SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

                // Read and display the data
                while (reader.Read())
                {.....`

Comment: `YourObject.Equals(System.DBNull.Value)` just tell you that `YourObject` has `null` value or not. suppose if you want to check your `img1` has `null` then first fetch its value from `datareader` then check its value by `img1.Equals(System.DBNull.Value)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it get Not Null Rows and then iterate those rows.

```
DataRow[] dr = dtbl.Select("img1 is Not Null");
 foreach (DataRow dr in dataRows)
 {

 }
```